# Dynamically updated AccountingForm

Tags: bugs, front-end, dynamic, number-representation, boxes

**Bug introduced in 10.4 or earlier and persisting through 11.1.1**

> CASE:3918306 confirmed

---

I freshly installed Wolfram Mathematica. I can't quite remember how to output a dynamically updated variable number $x$ in dollars?

I did improvise the following:

```
Manipulate[AccountingForm[x, {Infinity, 2}, DigitBlock -> {3, 2}, NumberSigns -> {"-$", "+$"}], {x, -100000000,100000000, .01}](*Shows tooltipped error: "AccountingForm: Value for option DigitBlock should be a positive integer, Infinity or a pair of positive integers."*)
```

Alternatively, I tried:

```
AccountingForm[Manipulate[x, {x, -100000000, 100000000, .01}], {Infinity, 2}, DigitBlock -> {3, 2}, NumberSigns -> {"-$","+$"}](*Problem: A number like "67.2" is not displayed as the expected "+$67.20."*)
```

The corresponding output for each  piece of code:

[image]

[image]

What's the code to output a dynamic variable number in dollars? For example, to show the numbers ${-6543.567, 556788.456789}$ as ${-$6,543.57, +$556,788.46}$.

---

Problem: Dynamically updating `AccountingForm[]`.

```
(*Does not work*) Manipulate[AccountingForm[x, {Infinity, 2}, DigitBlock -> {3, 2},NumberSigns -> {"-$", "+$"}], {x, -100000000, 1000000000, .01}]
```

Solution: Define `AccountingForm[]` as a new identical function (with the same desired parameters)

```
(*Does work*) Dollars[x_] := AccountingForm[x, {Infinity, 2}, DigitBlock -> {3, 2},NumberSigns -> {"-$", "+$"}]; Manipulate[Dollars[x], {x, -100000000, 1000000000, .01}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A workaround: Define a function that is identical to `AccountingForm` (with the options specified) and use it as the first argument in `Manipulate`

```
accountingForm = AccountingForm[#, {Infinity, 6}, DigitBlock -> {3, 2}, 
    NumberSigns -> {"-$", "+$"}] &;

Manipulate[accountingForm[x], {x, -10000, 10000, .0001}]
```

[image]

Also works in @Kuba's example:

```
Dynamic@accountingForm[-1234567890.123456]
```

> -$1,234,567,890.12 34 56

Same approach works for other number forms. For example, for `PaddedForm` (which, unlike `AccountingForm`, uses only the first number in `DigitBlock -> {3,2}`) we can do

```
ClearAll[paddedForm]
paddedForm = PaddedForm[#, {12, 6}, ExponentFunction -> (Null &), 
    DigitBlock -> {3, 2}, NumberSigns -> {"-$", "+$"}] &;

Dynamic@paddedForm[-1234567890.123456]
```

> -$1,234,567,890.12000000

Answer (score 3):

Here's a workaround:

```
Manipulate[
PaddedForm[x, {12, 2},
  ExponentFunction -> (Null &),
  DigitBlock -> 3,
  NumberSigns -> {"-$", "+$"}],
 {x, -100000000, 100000000, .01}]
```

[image]

The problem occurs if you dynamically update `DigitBlock -> {x, y}` (also with other number forms).

Comment: If one needs to use `DigitBlock -> 3` instead of `{3,2}` then there is no need to change anything more, is there?

Comment: If you don't use this workaround `.40` would display as `.4`

Comment: But this is what `AccountingForm` does anyway: `AccountingForm[.4, {Infinity, 2}, DigitBlock -> {3, 2},  NumberSigns -> {"-$", "+$"}]` so if this is a problem it is another one. But right, makes sense to use it.

Comment: @eldo So with  `DigitBlock -> 3`,  `.40` displays as `.40` and with `DigitBlock -> {3,2}` it displays as `.4`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler version that works directly:

```
Manipulate[
 AccountingForm[N[x], {Infinity, 2}, DigitBlock -> 3, 
  NumberSigns -> {"-$", "+$"}, 
  NumberPadding -> {"", "0"}], {x, -100000000, 100000000, .01}]
```

Notice that unlike most other versions presented here, it correctly displays the .00 for the initial value:

```
In[89]:= Manipulate[AccountingForm[N[x],{Infinity,2},DigitBlock->3, 
      NumberSigns->{"-$","+$"},NumberPadding->{"", "0"}],
      {x,-100000000,100000000,.01}]//Setting
Out[89]//AccountingForm= -$100,000,000.00
```

Using `DigitBlock->{3,2}` is useless if you're only ever going to display 2 digits based the decimal point.